# How do I get the name of the computer accessing my web page in VB?

Tags: vb.net, computer-name

I've already tried these methods:

- System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
- Environment.MachineName
- My.Computer.Name
- Environ$("computername")

Each returns APPDEV, which I assume is the name of the server hosting my web page.
I've even asked friends to try my page with these methods and they see the same thing.
How can I get it to return the PC name entered at initial setup, like Joseph-PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the browser won't tell the computer name to the server, a web page is (thankfully) not able to know your computer's name.

Comment: Ah, so I was on a hopeless quest then. Oh well, it would have been cool otherwise.

Comment: On a web page like a company intranet, you might be able to find out the computer's name by using the method Markus suggested. But over the internet, this is hardly possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Similarly, [UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) retrieves the IP of the client. But this information might not be valid in most circumstances due to (legitimate) privacy or network (NAT, Proxies, ...) reasons. So I wouldn't rely to strong on the presence or validity of the data.

If you are provided an IP address in UserHostName, you can use [System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make a DNS reverse lookup to find the name. This also might not work under all circumstances as not every client is registered at a DNS server.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName` returns the IP, not the PC name. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JosephWebber: as I wrote, don't rely on the validity of the information. You can still try to make a reverse lookup to get the name. I've updated the answer.